# Derivation of Ordinary Least-Squares Slope Estimate

Tags: statistics, proof-verification, statistical-inference, regression

I understand the reasoning behind the fact that $\hat{\beta}_1 \sim N(\beta_1,\frac{\sigma^2}{SSX})$. However, in trying to prove the full formula for estimating $\hat{\beta}_1$, I am having issues/don't know the reasoning behind this part of the formula:

$\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})(Y_i - \bar{Y})$ = $\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})Y_i$

Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Nothing much to explain. Just expand the l.h.s and r.h.s separately.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\sum (X_i - \bar{X})(Y_i - \bar{Y}) &=
\sum (X_i - \bar{X})Y_i - \sum (X_i - \bar{X})\bar{Y} \\
&=\sum (X_i - \bar{X})Y_i - \sum X_i\bar{Y} + n\bar{X}\bar{Y} \\
&= \sum (X_i - \bar{X})Y_i - n\bar{X}\bar{Y} + n\bar{X}\bar{Y}\\
&= \sum (X_i - \bar{X})Y_i 
\end{align}